# Issue reading space from file

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io, stream, getline

I am trying to read a line from a file that has spaces in it.  Despite everything I've tried and all my research, nothing seems to work, here is my current attemp

```
void read_name(fstream& in_file, comp& cmp)
{
   char buff[80];
   in_file.getline(buff, 79, '\n');
   in_file >> buff;

   cout << "NAME: " << buff << endl;

   cmp.set_name(buff);
   in_file.getline(buff, 79);
}
```

For whatever reason, this will still read until it sees a space and then stops.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm not that great with straight C++ so I could very well just be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

```
in_file.getline(buff, 79, '\n');
```

There.  You read a line (assuming the line wasn't longer than 78 characters).  So why'd you go and do this?

```
in_file >> buff;
```

That's going to overwrite the line you just read with the next word.  If you want the next line, then call getline again.

But it's better to use `std::string` and the free function `std::getline`, that way you don't have to specify line lengths.

```
std::string buff;
std::getline(in_file, buff);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't print out anything after "NAME:" void read_name(fstream& in_file, comp& cmp)
{
   std::string line;
   
   if (std::getline(in_file, line))
   {
      cout << "NAME: " << line << endl;
   }
   
   cmp.set_name(buff);
   in_file.getline(buff, 79);
}

Comment: @user1595510: Then something else is going wrong, perhaps the contents of the file aren't what you expect, I don't know.  I can't diagnose it without more information. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
in_file >> buff;
```

is wiping out the contents of buff which you've just read from the file.
If you step through your code with a debugger watching the contents of buff then you would see this happening.

Comment: 1) This should be a comment, not an answer. 2) A file opened in text mode (the default) takes care of differences in line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using c++ I recommend you use stl string instead of char arrays.

```
std::string linestr;
while( std::getline(input, linestr) )
{
   // process line
}
```

where input is your ifstream.

Comment: And since we're using standard C++, I recommend you call the C++ standard library "the C++ standard library", and not "STL" which it isn't.